# Ec primes and $1324$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Ec primes are primes of the form:

$(2^n-1)\cdot 10^d+2^{n-1}-1$, where d Is the Number of decimal digits of $2^{n-1}$.

n's leading to a prime are contained in the following bector:

$2,3,4,7,8,12,19,22,36,46,51,67,79,215,359,394,451,1323$

Now I call a(1)=2,a(2)=3,a(3)=4,...a(j) the j-th  component of the Vector of n's  leading to a prime.

Is It Just a coincidence that

$a(18)+1=a(1)+a(2)+...+a(16)$?

From here can be derived some recurrence relation or Is It Just a trivial relation?

Is there  $a(j)>1323$ such that $a(j)+1=a(1)+a(2)+...+a(j-2)$?

Comment: This seems pretty random, unless you have any other support to your claim.

Comment: @peppermint Have you not considered a simpler case, viz:
Ec primes are primes formed by concatenation in base 10 of two consecutive primes. For example:
23, 35,35,57,711,1113, etc.

Comment: @kabenyuk why should I? I consider ec primes. Probably ec primes are more interesting than your primes, although I am not sure.